# Retrieve a thumbnail of a video

Tags: java, android, video, multimedia

I'm trying to make an application for showing the best movie trailers. I'd like to show a grid view with the thumbnails of each video and then clicking them open a new Activity for playing the video.

Given a moment of the video, how can I retrieve the thumbnail? If that is complicated the first frame is enought too. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using API 2.0 or newer this will work.

To get video id:

```
String[] proj = {
    MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
    MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA
};

Cursor cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                                    proj, MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME+"=?",new String[] {"name.mp4"}, null);
cursor.moveToFirst()
id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));
```

To get the thumbnail of the video:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView ) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagePreview);
ContentResolver crThumb = getContentResolver();
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 1;
Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb, id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, options);
iv.setImageBitmap(curThumb);
```

***EDIT***:

If you are on android-8 (Froyo) or above, you can use [ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html#createVideoThumbnail%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) from video path:

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,
    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I do it if I have not a video_id because it is a video file in the sdcard? (keeping an API level 7+ if posible) Thanks