# How to retrieving a thumbnail of a video placed in a folder excluded from the media scan

Tags: java, android, video, thumbnails

I'm trying to get a thumbnail of a video. I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540798/retrieve-a-thumbnail-of-a-video) answer.

My problem is that the video I want to make the thumbnail is an file in a cache folder with an .nomedia file and for that reason the video doesn't appear in the media scan and the returned cursor is empty.

How can I solve that problem keeping the min sdk level =7?

Thanks!

Edit: Starting a bounty for the answer to that question: Retrieve a thumbnail for a video file in a folder at the filesystem which is excluded from media scan keeping the project Min SDK =7

Comment: Does it work if you explicitely call the mediascanner on the file ?

Answer (score 0):

Try force the scan of media file with a broadcast:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Comment: I dont want to add that file to the Android's gallery =(

Answer (score 0):

If you can make the video folder , i tell you to do this :

```
Context ctx = getContext();
File folder = ctx.getDir("NewFolder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

But like this answer says:

> You can't create such a folder on sdcard. **Everything that's saved onto
>   sdcard can be accessed by other applications**.

extracted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429312/can-i-create-password-protected-folder-in-android/5429822#5429822)